# Как в VS Code создать свои сворачиваемые области?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Есть довольно длинный(1319 строк) файл CSS, он разделен на области примерно так "---------Обнуление---------". Задолбало мышкой мотать туда-сюда, в google и в расширениях ничего подходящего не нашел. Может кто подсказать как можно настроить собственные области сворачивания, например задав "/*Начало Область обнуление" и "/*Конец" получить слева плюсик для сворачивания всего между этими двумя строками.

Comment: Я в таких случаях разделяю файл на несколько. На время разработки можно хранить CSS в разных файлах, по завершению работы объединять в один (при необходимости).

Comment: коментом пишете region, и аотом endregion...и vs code должен мочь сворачивать этот код

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц спасибо за ответ, но с регионами не сработало.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/485503/%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2 хорошая идея, походу ей и воспользуюсь. Спасибо.